# Thrifty Java EE setup for REST services and database

Tags: java, database, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I want to offer some REST services which collect data from a database and store passed data in this database. Because I work often with Java it is my prefered language instead of PHP, nodeJs or some other lightweight language/framework. 
AS prefered database I would use mySQL or PostgreSQL. 
To save some resources I want to use Jetty in combination with Jersey and Hibernate. For the frontend angularJS should help with its asynchronous behavior. 
Could this setup run with 500MB of RAM on a small virtual server (VServer) or would it be not enough? Is these a more frugal setup for my prefered language Java?

Many thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Going with Java for what you are suggesting is obviously going to take more resources than other obvious choices you mentioned. I'm like you though and like to use Java for this type of thing.

I have done a Jersey, MySql, AngularJS setup just you like you mentioned many times. 500 mb should be enough for you although it really depends on how large your project ends up being.

Comment: Is Hibernate the cost driver? Would it be more thrifty if we replace Hibernate with JPA? How much RAM could be saved? Maybe you can share your experience. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion Spring Boot is a nice way to have all your desired components up and running quickly and with minimal configuration (lots of convention-over-configuration and autoconfig).

If you're not familiar with Spring Boot, [the spring.io website](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) and its guides should get you up and running. Here is a simple guide to create your REST web service: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
(or search for tutorials and talks on youtube/vimeo).

Here you can see an memory footprint analysis of a Spring Boot app: https://spring.io/blog/2015/12/10/spring-boot-memory-performance

As you can see there, 512 MB should be plenty for a simple app.

Spring Boot uses Tomcat and Spring MVC by default with good Hibernate support. You could swap in Jetty (search for appropriate howtos), but Tomcat works really well.

Important (whichever framework you end up using) is to set the memory parameters of the JVM manually (see the memory performance post linked above).